# Laravel Eloquent - checking if returned object is valid or not

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

I'm retrieving objects using Laravel's Eloquent, and I'm trying to see if the object is valid or not.

For instance

`$user = User->where('first_name', 'Adam')->first(); // what if there are no Adams?`

I get a Builder object when there are no Adams and a User object when there is. Without using instanceof, is there a way to find out if the object returned is a valid User? Ideally, Eloquent would have just returned a null or some InvalidObject object as a response.

Comment: There is no way to return `Builder` from `first`. It's either `Model` or `null`, but mind that calling any Builder method on the `Model` **will** return `Builder`. Show entire code you  have.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

[`first`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/4.2/src/Illuminate/Database/Query/Builder.php#L1319) method return `null` if a model is not found, you may also use `firstOrFail` method to throw an exception

Comment: Unfortunately I get a Builder object instead.

Comment: and `firstOrFail` return the first result or throw an exception?

Comment: It turned out that another developer had overriden the first() method.

Answer (score 1):

If there are no matches for your query, then $user should be a falsey value

```
    if (!$user) {
        App::abort(404, 'User record does not exist');
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me hope it help others
I tried this and it worked for me

```
$model = Leadset::where('name',$data['name'])->first();
if(!$model) echo "no name found";
```